# Elixir - Convert a string number or empty string to a float or nil

Tags: ecto, elixir

I am trying to convert the `price` field, which is a string (eg `"2.22"` or `""`) to a float or nil, and then add it to the database.

```
  def insert_product_shop(conn, product_id, shop_id, price) do
    priceFloat = nil
    if price not in [""] do
      price = elem(Float.parse(price), 0)
      priceFloat = price / 1
      IO.inspect(priceFloat)
    else
      priceFloat = nil
    end
    IO.inspect(priceFloat)
    changeset = Api.ProductShop.changeset(%Api.ProductShop{
      p_id: product_id,
      s_id: shop_id,
      price: priceFloat,
      not_in_shop_count: 0,
      is_in_shop_count: 0
      })
    errors = changeset.errors
    valid = changeset.valid?
    IO.inspect(changeset)
    case insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, product_shop} ->
        {:ok, product_shop}
      {:error, changeset} ->
        {:error, :failure}
    end
  end
```

the output is:

```
2.22
nil
#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil, changes: %{}, errors: [], data: #Api.ProductShop<>,
 valid?: true>

13:25:41.745 [debug] QUERY OK db=2.0ms
INSERT INTO "product_shops" ("is_in_shop_count","not_in_shop_count","p_id","s_id") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4) RETURNING "id" [0, 0, 40, 1]
```

As the output shows, `priceFloat` becomes nil, I assume because when I set it to 2.22 it was out of scope. Maybe my code is too imperative. How can I rewrite this to convert "2.22" to 2.22 without making it nil, and allow "" to be converted to nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case` to evaluate the returned value by `Float.parse` and assign `nil` when it returns `:error`, assuming that the purpose of your `if` is to avoid the parsing error

```
def insert_product_shop(conn, product_id, shop_id, price) do
  priceFloat = case Float.parse(price) do
    {value, _remainder} -> value
    :error -> nil
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: This code is potentially dangerous because it’d happily accept `Float.parse("3.14some❤❤❤garbage")`.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin really? but the garbage would be left in the remainder, would't it? how could it be dangerous? I appreciate the comment BTW, it's always good to learn this stuff

Comment: The garbage would indeed be left in the remainder, but `1.0a` being successfully parsed as float, and `a1.0` returning the error does not seem to be super-consistent :)

Answer (score 2):

> As the output shows, priceFloat becomes nil, I assume because when I set it to 2.22 it was out of scope.

Almost right. Rather that the variable you are trying to set being out of scope, the problem is that the variable you assign to *inside* the if statement goes **out** of scope. It just happens to have the same name as the variable outside the if statement.

The solution is to assign the result of the if/else statement to the variable. Here is your code with minimal changes:

```elixir
price = "2.22"

priceFloat =
  if price not in [""] do
    elem(Float.parse(price), 0)
  else
    nil
  end

IO.inspect(priceFloat)
```

However, it's still not very idiomatic. You can take advantage of the fact that `Float.parse/1` returns `:error` when the input is the empty string to write it like with a `case` expression:

```elixir
priceFloat =
  case Float.parse(price) do
    {float, ""} -> float
    :error -> nil
  end
```

Comment: Blind `elem/2` is potentially dangerous because it’d happily deal with `Float.parse("3.14some❤❤❤garbage")`.

Comment: That's why I suggested matching against `{float, ""}`.

Comment: I know :) I just pointed out that you’d probably better mention this (it’s not only counter-idiomatic, it’s somewhat dangerous.)

Comment: Good point, I should have explained that explicitly in the answer, but now you did it for me ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of pattern matching and method overloading to solve the problem:

```elixir
defmodule Example do
  def parsePrice(""), do: nil
  def parsePrice(price) when is_float(price), do: price
  def parsePrice(price) when is_binary(price) do
    {float, _} = Float.parse(price)
    float
  end
end

Example.parsePrice(2.22) |> IO.inspect
Example.parsePrice("2.22") |> IO.inspect
```

(The equivalent is achievable using a `case` statement)

If you pass anything that is not a binary (a string) or a float to this function it will cause a pattern unmatched error. This may be good in case you have some error reporting in place, so you can detect unexpected usage of your code.

For a better debugging experience, I encourage you to use the built-in debugger via [`IEx.pry/0`](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/debugging.html#iexpry0-and-iexbreak2).

Comment: Thanks! I get an error when I pass in `""`: `(MatchError) no match of right hand side value: :error`. I would like to return `nil` under the scenario that `price` is `""`.

Comment: `{float, _}` pattern match is potentially dangerous because it’d happily match `Float.parse("3.14some❤❤❤garbage")`.

Comment: Also, `def parsePrice(""), do: nil` clause is redundant, an empty string would be ruled out by `Float.parse/1` on its own.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of diversity, I’d post another approach that uses [`with/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html?#with/1) special form.

```rb
with {f, ""} <- Float.parse("3.14"),
  do: f,
  else: (_ -> nil)
```

Here we explicitly match the float only. Any trailing garbage would be discarded. If the match succeeds, we return the float, otherwise, we return `nil`.

---

Beware of [`Float.parse/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Float.html?#parse/1) might be confused by garbage that looks like scientific notation.

```rb
(with {f, ""} <- Float.parse("3e14"), do: f) == 300_000_000_000_000
#⇒ true
```

---

***Important sidenote***: assigning `priceFloat` inside `if` does not change the value of the `priceFloat` variable outside of the scope. Scoping in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) is pretty important and one cannot propagate local variables to the outermost scope, unlike most of the languages.

```rb
foo = 42
if true, do: foo = 3.14
IO.puts(foo)
#⇒ 42
```

Well, to some extent it’s possible to affect outermost scope variables from macros with [`var!/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html?#var!/2), and `if` is indeed a macro, but this whole stuff is definitely far beyond the scope of this question.